# Why the browser hung by my Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to loop through all elements in the web page, however, it hangs.
I found that it loop the last <p> and <strong> element repeatly.
I tried to find the problem in the debugger of Firefox and Chrome , however,  I cannot find the root cause.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        kkjlkjjklk
        <div id=qq>
            sdfsdfdfdssdfsdf
        <p id="demo">Click the button get info about 
            the body element's child nodes</p>
        </div>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id=jj>
            <strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text 
            is considered as nodes.
        </p>

        <script>
        function showElementInfo(e)
        {
            var result="";
          var c=e.childNodes;
          for (i=0; i<c.length; i++)
          {
            data=jQuery.trim(c[i].textContent);
            switch (c[i].nodeName)
            {
                case "BUTTON":break;
              case "SCRIPT":break;
                default:
                                if (c[i].childNodes.length==3)
                                    showElementInfo(c[i]);
                                else
                                    console.log("parent="+c[i].parentNode.nodeName+","+c[i].nodeName+":"+data+","+c[i].childNodes.length);
                                break;
            }
          }
        }
        function myFunction()
        {
         var txt="";
         showElementInfo(document.body);
         //showElementInfo(document.getElementById("jj"));
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you very much

Comment: You could comment out all code expect for the for-loop. If your browser is still alive, uncomment the `data=...` part, then uncomment parts of the switch-clause and so on..

Comment: It shouldn't hang, it should break. There's a syntax error about a missing brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it hangs. I found that it loop the last `<p>` and `<strong>` element repeatly, however, I cannot find the root cause.

Your `i` variable is [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). When you do recursion, it will overwrite the counter variable in the outer call, and whenever the number of child nodes is smaller than the current `i` you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Lessons learned: Always use [`var` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), and use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) to be warned about mistakes early.